# Update embed fields with DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to update a field on a posted embed :

```
message.embeds[0].fields[0] = "New content";
```

But the embed message doesn't update.
I've tried to update the message :

```
function doAfakeEdit(message){
  message.edit(message.content);
}
```

It still keeps the old value of the field.
What should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Very late answer. But just in case someone finds this. Theres a much shorter way.

And more useful if you have large embeds and don't want to rebuild your whole embed:

```js
message.embeds[0].fields[0] = "Some much like";
message.edit(new Discord.RichEmbed(message.embeds[0]));
```

Comment: This is even better than the current answer

Answer (score 10):

I wonder if your problem is that you're either re-using variable names, putting the old data back into the edited message, or something else. Anyway, here's something that worked for me:

1) Create an `Embed` to send to the user (I assume you already did this, creating the `Embed` you showed on imgr):

```
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed({
  title: 'Suggestion by someone',
  description: 'This is a test suggestion. Can you please like it or dislike it :)',
  fields: [{
    name: 'Like:',
    value: '<3'
  }]
});
```

2) Send `Embed` to your channel (I added some `Reaction`s to it - possibly the same way as you):

```
// add reaction emojis to message
message.channel.send(embed)
  .then(msg => msg.react('✅'))
  .then(mReaction => mReaction.message.react('❎'))
  .then(mReaction => {
    // fun stuff here
  })
  .catch(console.log);
```

3) Create a `ReactionCollector` inside where I put `// fun stuff here` (you can use a different `reactionFilter` and time limit):

```
const reactionFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅';

// createReactionCollector - responds on each react, AND again at the end.
const collector = mReaction.message
  .createReactionCollector(reactionFilter, {
    time: 15000
  });

// set collector events
collector.on('collect', r => {
  // see step 4
});
// you can put anything you want here
collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} reactions`));
```

4) In the `'collect'` event (where I put `// see step 4`), create a new `Embed` with mostly similar values (or not - you change whatever you want), then put that new `Embed` back into the original message via `.edit(...)`:

```
// immutably copy embed's 'Like:' field to new obj
let embedLikeField = Object.assign({}, embed.fields[0]);

// update 'field' with new value - you probably want emojis here
embedLikeField.value = '<3 <3 <3';

// create new embed with old title & description, new field
const newEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed({
  title: embed.title,
  description: embed.description,
  fields: [embedLikeField]
});

// edit message with new embed
// NOTE: can only edit messages you author
r.message.edit(newEmbed)
  .then(newMsg => console.log(`new embed added`)) // this is not necessary
  .catch(console.log); // useful for catching errors
```

So the whole thing ends up looking something like this:

```
const reactionFilter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅';

const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed({
  title: 'Suggestion by someone',
  description: 'This is a test suggestion. Can you please like it or dislike it :)',
  fields: [{
    name: 'Like:',
    value: '<3'
  }]
});

// add reaction emoji to message
message.channel.send(embed)
  .then(msg => msg.react('✅'))
  .then(mReaction => mReaction.message.react('❎'))
  .then(mReaction => {
    // createReactionCollector - responds on each react, AND again at the end.
    const collector = mReaction.message
      .createReactionCollector(reactionFilter, {
        time: 15000
      });

    // set collector events
    collector.on('collect', r => {
      // immutably copy embed's Like field to new obj
      let embedLikeField = Object.assign({}, embed.fields[0]);

      // update 'field' with new value
      embedLikeField.value = '<3 <3 <3';

      // create new embed with old title & description, new field
      const newEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed({
        title: embed.title,
        description: embed.description,
        fields: [embedLikeField]
      });

      // edit message with new embed
      // NOTE: can only edit messages you author
      r.message.edit(newEmbed)
        .then(newMsg => console.log(`new embed added`))
        .catch(console.log);
    });
    collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} reactions`));
  })
  .catch(console.log);
```

For my code, edits are only made when the ✅ emoji is pressed, just for fun. Please let me know if you need help editing the code above. Hope it helps.

Comment: Well that was quite a long message for just "edit the message with a new embed" but it worked :) Thank you ;)