# Is there an event for when users remove reactions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I followed [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671344/8523281) and had everything working just right, but now I want an event that is triggered when the user **removes** the reaction from the message.

To give an example, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJtZD.gif), the user needs to react 2 times to change the 'page'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
client.on("messageReactionRemove", (reaction) => {
  console.log("Someone removed an reaction!");
});
```

This will send a message to the console that someone removed a reaction.
This is not 100% perfect but should do for that task.

You can read more about it [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionRemove).

Answer (score 0):

`messageReactionRemove` is the event fired when a reaction is removed from a message.
You can read more in the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionRemove).