# Trying to edit a specific embed field on a user action

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to triggering an edit on my embedded (already sent) message while keeping all the other fields the same value

I have found this answer as an inspiration (which works with the example): [Update embed fields with DiscordJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668366/embed-message-doesnt-update) but that doesn't seem to get all the fields, only the first. There isn't much more on the subject to find (or i'm not good at Googling :)).

So the new embed is just the first field and not all the (not changed) fields.

```
    activityMsg = new Discord.RichEmbed({
      title: 'Some text',
      description: 'Description',
      color: 3447003,
      footer: {
        icon_url: image,
        text: image
      },
      thumbnail: {
        url: image
      },
      fields: [
        {
          name: 'Text',
          value: 'Text2',
        },
        {
          name: 'Date and time',
          value: '2pm',
        },
        {
          name: 'Participants',
          value: '@User',
        },
        {
          name: 'Waiting list',
          value: '@user2',
        },
        {
          name: 'Max players',
          value: '22',
        }
      ]
    });

    const reactionFilterPlus = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === emoji_plus;

    if(typeof title != undefined && title != null && data.length == 4 && error == ''){
      var title = title[0].replace('[','').replace(']','');
  
      // add reaction emoji to message
      msg.channel.send(activityMsg)
        .then(msg => msg.react(constants.emoji_plus))
        .then(mReaction => {
          // createReactionCollector - responds on each react, AND again at the end.
          const collector = mReaction.message
            .createReactionCollector(reactionFilterPlus, {
              time: 15000
            });
  
          // set collector events
          collector.on('collect', r => {
            // immutably copy embed's Like field to new obj
            let embedLikeField = Object.assign({}, activityMsg.fields[0]);
  
            // update 'field' with new value
            embedLikeField.value = `${user} <3`;
  
            // create new embed with old title & description, new field
            const newEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed({
              title: activityMsg.title,
              description: activityMsg.description,
              fields: [embedLikeField]
            });
  
            // edit message with new embed
            // NOTE: can only edit messages you author
            r.message.edit(newEmbed)
              .catch(console.log);
          });
        })
        .catch(console.log);
      }
```

I expected this line to get all the fields, but that isn't the case.

```
   // immutably copy embed's Like field to new obj
   let embedLikeField = Object.assign({}, activityMsg.fields[0]);
```

I have tried `let embedLikeField = Object.assign({}, activityMsg.fields[0] === 'Participants')` but then I get the following error about a fieldname not present.

```
{ DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.fields[0].name: This field is required
    at item.request.gen.end (/usr/src/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:79:15)
    at then (/usr/src/app/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:215:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

English isn't my native language and I'm stilling learning nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Object.assign() performes a shallow clone on the source, Are you trying to clone your entire embed or only its first field?

`activityMsg.fields[0]` refers to the first element in the list called fields within your activityMsg object. Try calling your assign() with activityMsg as source.