# Update an embed message that already exists in Discord

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to update an embed message that my bot has already written in a specific channel, how can I do that? If i try to use message.edit it givesthis error: *discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50005): Cannot edit a message authored by another user*

```
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands

def write_json(data,filename="handle.json"):
    with open (filename, "w") as f:
        json.dump(data,f,indent=4)

class Handle(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client=client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Modulo_Handle: ON")

    @commands.command()
    async def Handlers(self,ctx):
            with  open('handle.json','r') as file:
                data = json.load(file)
                embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(data)
                await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
                file.close()

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):    
        if str(message.channel) == "solaris™-handle":
            author = message.author
            content = message.content
            user = str(author)
            with open ("handle.json") as file:
                data = json.load(file)
                temp = data['fields']
                y={"name":user[:-5],"value":content}
                temp.append(y)
                write_json(data)
                updated_embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(data)
                await message.edit(embed=updated_embed)
                file.close()
            

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Handle(client))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed message doesn't update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668366/embed-message-doesnt-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
msg_id = 875774528062640149
channel = self.client.get_channel(875764672639422555)
msg = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
with  open('handle.json','r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(data)
await msg.edit(embed=embed)
```

Fixed adding this code below `write_json(data)` and remove
`updated_embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(data)` `await message.edit(embed=updated_embed)`